# How can I let a Wine application send keystrokes to the Linux host?

Tags: linux, wine, midi

I have a windows Electron app running through `wine-staging` that lets me use a midi device for a few different functions such as sound effects, HTTP requests, and keybinds. The app is so old that all my attempts to compile and package it for Linux from source have failed (`npm install` can't find the packages), which is why I'm running it through Wine.

The sound playing and (surprisingly) HTTP functions work fine, but it seems unable to send keystrokes to Linux. I've seen lots of posts on sending keys to Wine with Bash or similar, but nothing for the other way around. Are there any solutions for this?

As far as I can tell from the source, the program uses IPC and RobotJS for sending keystrokes, which is absolutely overkill (as confirmed by posts on stackoverflow haha).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you are kinda asking for help with that particular program, which is fine by me. But to help you it would be usefull, to actually know what application you are talking about? My guess is actually, that the software you are using is not too old to being viable for linux, but that there are probably hard windows dependecies in the code, so it cant be compiled for linux without modifications. You are probably better of, searching for an alternative linux software.